# Play-2.2.1 p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I am new to the Play Framework 2.2.1. Recently I got strange errors from the nettyException.

Okay, here is the thing, I develop a Play project in Java. It works well in Mac. When I move the project to CentOS 6.5 server, and type command "play start" to run the application. I periodically (about every 3 minutes) got errors:

---

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty.jar:na]

---

However, when I create a totally new helloworld project using "play new helloworld" and run it by both "play start" and "play run", these errors still exist.

I have tried all possible solution I found from the Internet, but none of them solves my problem.

Any folk has any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Regards.

Steven.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when testing a play application on my local machine. Turned out the test requests I was sending were using **HTTPS** when really they should of course have been plain old **HTTP**.

Comment: It could also be a port scanner, which opens a random port on your server and tries to send it data.